# React Flux multiple store communication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I'm facing a problem with Flux architecture in a React application. Here is what I have :

- Store A with objects that have two main fields : "name" and "id"
- Store B which has a dependency to objects' field "name" present in store A
- An API that I can't change which send the value "id" of a store A's object
- An action that is fetching informations from the API

The problem is that the API sends me an information that store B needs to handle (thanks to the dispatcher) to update the "name" (field from store A).

So : API sends me "id" but in my store B I need to have the "name". According to the Flux architecture I can't communicate directly from my Action to my Store A, so I can't call any function like "getNameById". The "id" field was only added on the application because of the information sent by the API.

Without changing the API, how can I manage to have this "remapping" from "id" to "name" and where to put it ? I can't see where this has to be in a Flux architecture.

Thanks !

Comment: A selector should be able to pull the name from store A for your consumer

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean by "selector" ? 
I've a function called getNameById, but from flux architecture I can't call it from an action of my application, if I'm correct.

Comment: How the API send the information to Store A? Who calls the API? Does the API returns only the ID? How Store A have the `name` information if the API does not return the `name`? Only Store A have the `name` information, like a map between id and name?